# Error Performing OCR in UIPATH while reading Text from an PDF containing Image(Abby,microsoft,google)

Tags: ocr, abbyy, uipath, rpa

**I want to extract text from a PDF containing Image for which I am using UIPath.
I have tried Abby, microsoft and google OCR engine but getting same error in all of them.
Below is the error stacktrace:-**

```
ExtractMail has thrown an exception

Source: Abbyy OCR

Message: Error performing OCR: AbbyyErrorLoadEngine

Exception Type: Exception

System.Exception: Error performing OCR: AbbyyErrorLoadEngine

Server stack trace: 
   at UiPath.Vision.VisionClient.ScrapeUsingHostService(OCRInput input, OCROptions options, CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at UiPath.Vision.VisionClient.ScrapeImage(OCRInput input, OCROptions options, CancellationToken cancelToken, Boolean useHostProcess)
   at UiPath.Vision.VisionClient.Scrape(OCRInput input, OCROptions options, CancellationToken cancelToken, Boolean useHostProcess)
   at UiPath.Vision.UiImage.ScrapeOCR(OCROptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at UiPath.Core.Activities.OCREngineActivity.<>c__DisplayClass36_0.<BeginExecute>b__0()
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, IMessageSink replySink)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.EndInvokeHelper(Message reqMsg, Boolean bProxyCase)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RemotingProxy.Invoke(Object NotUsed, MessageData& msgData)
   at System.Func`1.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult result)
   at UiPath.Core.Activities.OCREngineActivity.EndExecute(AsyncCodeActivityContext context, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Activities.AsyncCodeActivity`1.System.Activities.IAsyncCodeActivity.FinishExecution(AsyncCodeActivityContext context, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Activities.AsyncCodeActivity.CompleteAsyncCodeActivityData.CompleteAsyncCodeActivityWorkItem.Execute(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you have a problem executing `UiPath.Vision.Host32.exe` (in 18.2+ it's located in `C:\Users\<username>\.nuget\packages\uipath.vision\<version number>\build\UiPath.Vision.Host32.exe`). It could be blocked by AV software or group policies. Try checking with [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to see if you'll get any hints about what is going on.